# Domino 9.0.0 and 9.0.1 Xpage differences in XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Developing an Xpages application for deployment on the client (thus running XPiNc). My Lotus Client and Designer Client is 9.0.1, but most of the rest of the company is running 9.0.0. Our server is 9.0.0.

I notice now that the application is running differently on people who have version 9.0.0. Things don't work like they do on mine and it looks different. I am using the ExtLib extensively and also dojo.

I have set the setting to compile this application to run on to 9.0.0 and recompiled (it was set to "minimum release for Xpage features used" and I recompiled, no changes.

I have not put in a minimum dojo version.

We can upgrade the server if that would fix things.

How can I be sure to develop databases that can be run on XPiNC by everyone?

=================================Response====================================
1. I am running it as "local." I did try the run on server on our test server, but the security didn't work.

1. My screen looks like this:
   [image]

Other's screen looks like this:

What is worse, is that the Value Pickers don't work for others.........

[image]

========================================================

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:djextListTextBox id="Approvers" multipleTrim="true"
        displayLabel="true" styleClass="formFields"
        value="#{document1.ACHApprovers}">
        <xe:this.multipleSeparator><![CDATA[#{javascript:"\n"}]]></xe:this.multipleSeparator>
    </xe:djextListTextBox>
    <xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker2"
        dialogTitle="Choose From Exempt Employee(s)" pickerIcon="/picker.png"
        for="Approvers" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:dominoViewValuePicker viewName="(EmployeesExempt)">
                <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var serv:String = session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer();
serv + "!!" + "TheTruth.nsf";}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
            </xe:dominoViewValuePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:valuePicker>
    </xp:view>
```

And here are my XSP properties:

```
xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=false
xsp.persistence.mode=file
xsp.resources.aggregate=true
xsp.error.page.default=true
xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library
xsp.theme=oneuiv2.1
xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true
xsp.min.version=9.0.0
```

=============================

Also the error the other users are getting when they click the value picker is

## "Invalid template: line #232 DBName.nsf

Comment: A couple of questions. 1) Are you running it as a "local" XPages app or with "Run server-based XPages apps directly on the server" ticked? 2) Can you give some examples of how it's working / looking differently?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? I want to see specifically how you are calling style classes and what classes. Also I would be interested in knowing the theme you are using. Also if the lookups fail can you post the code for the lookups? I have xpinc apps that file on lots of lookups and have a piece of code that "may" help...

Comment: Patrick, I posted the code to a small Xpage and the xsp properties. I do not use any custom css on this page. Any help you could provide would be much much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

> How can I be sure to develop databases that can be run on XPiNC by everyone?

Make sure that the server and client versions are exactly the same. You will have differences between versions.

Make sure that if you use the extlib you are not using the extlibx (they are different).

Or you can use run xpages on the server instead of "real" xpinc.

[edit]

After looking at your code and your error I would try making a local replica of the application and see if you can run it from there and if at the very least the lookup works. The way that I understand lookups with xpinc is that xpinc runs the app as if it is on a server. So the database if "thetruth.nsf" is the name of the database would need to be local. I would also try specify the path with server name and  database path as the XPINC app is looking at the local notes client when trying to do the lookup.

[edit2]
The way to think of xpinc is an adorable little half assed server that sits on a client machine.

Comment: I personally wish that xpinc worked well, but its too slow, doesn't authenticate the way I want, requires too many programming changes its just easier for me to tell people to go to the web. Maybe if IBM switched from firefox to chrome as a rendering engine I would get some better response times for the js stuff... so IBM when is Blink coming...

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your app after setting the minimum version used in XSP settings to the productive environment, in your case 9.0.0. If it compiles it should work on your server AND in XPiNC as well. Don't forget to clean the project.

Comment: Oliver, this is a good idea and I have tried this, but users STILL get the difference. There is no difference between when I compile with the target at 9.0.0 and 9.0.1.

Comment: Perhaps you need to downgrade your development environment to 9.0.0 to make sure the compilation works correctly. Sometimes, the development team needs to be the LAST ones to upgrade.